# How to access items from an implemented PLIST dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, tableview, plist

I've pulled items from a plist and implemented them into a dictionary, however I'm not quite sure how to unwrap and make these items available from a variable. Heres what I have:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,
    UITableViewDataSource {

   // Loading in the PLIST file
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   }
    var courses = loadCSCourses()

    //variables
    var courseData = courses["CS 1400"]
    var shortDescription = courseData["ShortDescription"]
    var courseKeys = Array(courses.keys)
    @IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBAction func whenSwitchOn (sender:AnyObject) {
        if (mySwitch.isOn){
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func sortingCourseKeys() {
        courseKeys.sort()
    }
    // The number of rows
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return courses!.count
    }

    // The number of cells in each row
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        //Naming the Title and Subtitle line
        cell.textLabel?.text = "course name"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "course description"
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

        return cell
    }

    // Selecting and deslecting rows
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = courseKeys[indexPath.row]
        if cell.contains(courseKeys[indexPath.row]) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }else{
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
        return
    }
}

func loadCSCourses() -> [String : [String : String]]? {
    let pListFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "CSCourses", withExtension: "plist", subdirectory: "")
    if let pListPath = pListFileURL?.path,
        let pListData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: pListPath) {
        do {
            let pListObject = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: pListData, options:PropertyListSerialization.ReadOptions(), format:nil)
            guard let maybeCourses = pListObject as? [String : [String : String]] else {
                return nil
            }
            return maybeCourses
        } catch {
            print("Error reading CSCourses plist file: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I am getting the errors:
Cannot use instance member 'courses' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
&
Value of optional type '[String : [String : String]]?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type '[String : [String : String]]'

Any hints, links, or help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is that you are using a class method before self is initialized. You have a few options:

Override the init function and set your variable there

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    courses = loadCSCourses()
}
```

Make your variable a lazy var

```
lazy var courses = loadCSCourses()
```

Make the function loadCSCourses() static, although I wouldn't recommend this.

Keep in mind the way you are defining:

```
var courseData = courses["CS 1400"]
var shortDescription = courseData["ShortDescription"]
var courseKeys = Array(courses.keys)
```

Is also too early, move this to init, after self is defined (or follow the 2. option)